# I want create item with attachment in SharePoint online with SPHttpClient context?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, attachments, sphttpclient

Below code is attaching file but not all files, means some time 2 file some time 3 file, some time one file but not attaching all file at all in loop.

```
 private btnclick_BtnSubmit = (): void => {
 
  let message = "Are you sure for submit this request?";
  var flag = this.validateControll();
  if(flag=="false")
  {
   
     var ParrentAppsParameterSource = this.getQueryStringVAlue()["source"];
     var ParparentrentAppsParameterParrent= this.getQueryStringVAlue()["parent"];  

    if (confirm(message) == true) {
         this.createItem(); 
         this.getAllFileInputWithinDiv(this.state.lastItemID)
           )       

     jQuery("#mdsSubmitting").show();
     jQuery("#divSubmitButton").hide();
  
     setTimeout(function() {
     this.getAllFileInputWithinDiv(this.state.lastItemID)
      alert("Your request have been submitted succesfully")
     location.href ="/sites/SharePointDevComm/SitePages/MapNav.aspx?parent="+ParparentrentAppsParameterParrent+"&source="+ParrentAppsParameterSource;
            }, 5000);

        } else {
      
       }
      } 
  }
```

```
//Multiple file attachment
 //Start
 
 private getAllFileInputWithinDiv= (itemID): void =>{             
  var id;
  let arrayFiles=[]; 
  jQuery("#attachment :input").each(function(e){    
      id = this.id;
      arrayFiles.push(id);  
       });
       
       for (var i=0;i<arrayFiles.length;i++)
       {
       await this.attachedFile(arrayFiles[i],itemID)
      }
      }

private attachedFile= (fileID , itemid): void =>{

  itemid=2;
 
  let file = (document.querySelector("#"+fileID) as HTMLInputElement).files[0];  

       if (file) { 
           let spOpts : ISPHttpClientOptions  = {
             headers: {
               "Accept": "application/json",
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
             },
             body: file     
           };
          var url = this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl  + `/_api/web/lists(guid'ac8ea99a-6add-4ccc-a753-cb37de256ba')/items(`+itemid+`)` + `/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='` + file.name +`')`;
            this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, spOpts).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
           if(Number(`${response.status}`) >300)
             {
               alert('Error Uploading file, Try again or contact IT . Please check if you are uploading any duplicate file');
              return;
             }
             response.json().then((responseJSON: JSON) => {
               console.log(responseJSON);                 
             });
           });        
       } }


    private addFileButton= (): void =>{
                    this.setState({
                    fileNumber: this.state.fileNumber+1
                      });
                     var FileAttachment="FileAttachment"+this.state.fileNumber.toString();                    
                       jQuery("#attachment").append('<div><input type="file" name="Attachment" style={{ paddingTop: "5px" }} id="'+FileAttachment+'" /><a href="#"><span style="width: 900px;float:right;color:blue;margin-top:-20px" class="spnBrowseFile">Delete</span></a></div>')

                          }
```

```
                    
                        
// Html Code 

  <div id="attachment">

          <h4><b>Attached Files :</b></h4>
</div>
           <br></br>
       <div><input type="button" id="bntAddAtachment" value="Add Attachment"  onClick={this.addFileButton}/></div>
      <div > <span style={{ color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bolder' }} id="spnErrorMessage" ></span>  </div>
        </div>
          <div style={{ width: '100%', marginLeft: '38%' }}>
          <div className={styles.button} id="divSubmitButton" onClick={this.btnclick_BtnSubmit} >
              <span className={styles.label} >Submit</span>
          </div>
```